# How to grant execution rights on DBMS packages to a PDB user?

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c

I'd like to grant execution right on `dbms_lock` package to a [local PDB user](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/users.htm#DBSEG468).

I have created new PDB with a local administrative user. I'm assuming I can use that local user for all management tasks in PDB. But when I try to grant execution right on `dbms_lock` to another local user I get `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.

I'm using Oracle 12c [database app development VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#dbapp).

The steps to re-produce the problem:

**Create new PDB as CDB SYS user**

[Creating a PDB Using the Seed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_plug.htm#ADMIN13566)

```
create pluggable database test1
admin user test1admin identified by test1admin
roles = (DBA)
file_name_convert = ('/pdbseed/', '/test1/')
;

alter pluggable database test1 open;
```

**Log in to PDB as test1admin and create new local non-administrative user**

```
create user test1 identified by test1;
grant connect to test1;
grant execute on dbms_lock to test1;

Error starting at line : 3 in command -
grant execute on dbms_lock to test1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

I have used `test1admin` succesfully to grant several other privileges to th elocal users. I have also verified `test1admin` user has access to `dbms_lock` package. But it seems that `dbms_lock`-package (and btw `dbms_crypto` too) is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, noone is granted the `EXECUTE` privilege on `DBMS_LOCK` **with grant option**. Even the `DBA` role does not have the grant option. `test1admin` has access to `DBMS_LOCK`, but `test1admin` is not authorized to grant privileges on `DBMS_LOCK` to additional users. You need to connect as `SYS` to grant privileges on `DBMS_LOCK` to additional users.

Connect to the CDB root as `SYS` and switch to your pluggable database:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
alter session set container = test1;
```

Or connect to the PDB directly:

```
sqlplus sys@test1 as sysdba
```

And issue the grant:

```
grant execute on dbms_lock to test1;
```

If you want `test1admin` to be able to grant privileges to `DBMS_LOCK` to others, then as `SYS`, issue the below:

```
grant execute on dbms_lock to test1admin with grant option;
```